# Can only run one VBA over 1 workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run Combine over several workbooks. When I run the following code, it only runs over one workbook and then closes and doesn't continue to the next wb. Any help would be great.

```
Sub AllFiles()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

folderPath = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\OCCREPORTS\Files\" 'change to suit

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
Do While filename <> ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
    wb.Activate
    Call Combine
    filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Combine()
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim LastCol As Integer


On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"


For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Name <> "Combined" Then
            Application.Goto Sheets(s.Name).[A1]
            Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
            Sheet.UsedRange.Clear
            LastCol = Sheets("Combined").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined"). _
            Cells(1, LastCol + 1)
        End If
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: `filename = Dir` should read `filename = Dir()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I made the change, but it still only loops through 1 file.

Comment: I got it to loop through the files, but its not executing the Combine ( I was running it from the wrong directory).

Comment: try changing `Combine` to `Call Combine`

Comment: I made the change. It loops through the files, but still doesn't execute Combine

Comment: does it meant it opens the workbooks without doing anything to them?

Comment: Yes. It opens the files, but doesn't do anything. I tested Sub Combine() on one file, and it works perfectly. But when I try to loop, it just opens the files, and does nothing.

Comment: I think it has to do with the way the my subs are formatting. Any ideas?

Comment: i am kinda lost to reasons why it doesn't run. Just an assumption: before you do `Call Combine` try adding `wb.Activate`

Comment: Updated the code above, its still opening all of the files, but only executing Combine on the first one.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` - what happens when you run it?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"` That is not the active worksheet.  that is the worksheet of the calling function so it will only run the one workbook you run the code with and add the sheet there.  Then your for each loop wont execute because there won't be a sheet named "Combined"

Comment: Run-time error '1004'Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: @chancea, should I add Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined" 

into the for loop?

Comment: just add the `ActiveWorkbook` infront of them like you do with the other calls do `Sheets`.

Comment: It still only loops through 1 workbook ... 
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"

Comment: what line do you get an error on when you remove the `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: I get Run-time error '424': Object required

Comment: Would it be easier for me to merge everything in my first tab? (All tabs in the workbooks are all labeled the same). "VINCasesAndCampaigns"

Comment: You can also have `wb` passed on as an argument to the `combine` sub and force all sheets to be assigned to it by specifying that passed argument as workbook

Comment: Raugmor, Sorry; I have zero clue what you just said. Can you explain?

Comment: Can explain, but will have to be tomorrow,  haven't got computer to hand, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following from my suggestions in comments, try passing the file info to the `Call` sub as an argument, please see below:

```
Sub AllFiles()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook

folderPath = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\OCCREPORTS\Files\" 'change to suit

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
Do While filename <> ""
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Call Combine(folderPath & filename)
  filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Combine(fileToOpen As String)
Dim J As Integer
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen)
With wb

  On Error Resume Next
  .Sheets(1).Select
  Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
  .Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"


  For Each s In .Sheets
    If s.Name <> "Combined" Then
        Application.Goto .Sheets(s.Name).[A1]
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        .Sheet.UsedRange.Clear
        LastCol = .Sheets("Combined").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Selection.Copy Destination:=.Sheets("Combined"). _
        Cells(1, LastCol + 1)
    End If
  Next
  .Save
  .Close
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Raugmor, if I wanted to take this one step further, and for every new sheet that was made with the title 'combined' how could we take  the new sheet and add it to the next free row in a new workbook called Target?

Comment: Add new sheet to free row? I'm not sure I follow. Could you please clarify?

Comment: For every "Combined" sheet that is created, the program copies the  entire "Combined" tab and places it into a new workbook called Target by the next free row.